# Prolog how to save file in an existing file

Tags: file, io, prolog

How do I save on an existing file after adding new data

```
add_a_link(X,Y) :-
    tell('alink.txt'),
    write(X),
    write('.'),
    write(Y),
    write('.'),
    put(10),
    told,
    write('data written'),
    nl.
```

this code only re-write the text file.

Answer (score 3):

Use `open/3` and stream oriented I/O:

```
open(file, append, S), write(S, info(X,Y)), put_char(S,.), nl(S), close(S).
```

Using `tell/1` and `told` is extremely unreliable. It easily happens that the output is written to another file accidentally.

Edit: Here is an example to illustrate the extremely unreliable properties of `tell/1` and `told`.

Say, you write `tell(file), X > 3, write(biggervalue), told.` This works fine as long as `X > 3`. But with a smaller value this query fails and nothing is written. That might have been your intention. However, the next output somewhere else in your program will now go into the `file`. That's something you never want to happen. For this reason ISO-Prolog does not have `tell/1` and `told` but rather `open/3` and `close/1`.

Comment: btw, the same could happen if you used aliases;  open(bar,write,_S,[alias(out)]),
 X>3,
 write(out,42),
 close(out).
for example. then if you had already another out alias the same problem would occur. so basically the main problem is impurity. of course, it's  definitely easier to make such a mistake using tell/told since the 'alias' is not explicitly declared

Comment: add_a_link(X,Y):-open('alink.txt',append,S),write(S, info(X,Y))put_char(S,.),nl(S),close(S). gave me a instances error

Comment: @thanosQR: aliases have a similar yet less virulent problem. You have to use the same alias in two different places in order to get the problems you describe.

Comment: @FrankJaeger: The `S` is a stream-term. The subsequent goals then refer to it. You probably got the instantiation error because you entered the subsequent goals in a different query.

Comment: I've a little confused on the stream term, I've look some notes around the internet but still not sure what is it. any examples of it?

Comment: It's a handle to refer to the opened stream. And it differs from implementation to implementation.

Comment: owh ya, is it possible that caused by a win prolog? cause I've tried all method but still result error.

Comment: Above code is ISO Prolog. And quasi all systems do it that way.  Try to type in on the toplevel `open(afile,append,S)` you should get an answer like `S = streamterm(2121)`. Otherwise consider another system, like B, GNU, IF, SWI, YAP...

Comment: | ?- open('city.txt',append,S)
     .
! ----------------------------------------
! Error 22 : Instantiation Error
! Goal     : open('city.txt',append,_11772)
it result like this, i guess it is the win prolog's issue. Sorry for didn't mention earlier.

Comment: OK, then this system is really broken. There are many systems out there - see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info)