# Writing to file (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to loop through a list and writing it to a file, why is the following not working?

```
loop_through_list(List) :-
    member(Element, List),
    write(Element),
    write(' '),
    fail.   

write_list_to_file(Filename,List) :-
    tell(Filename),     % open file to be written 
    loop_through_list(List),
    told.               % flush buffer
```

Comment: Look into the file you created when running `write_list_to_file/2`! Quite probably it will not only have the elements of the list in it, but also some other unintended data at the end of the file. As others have already remarked, using `open/3` and `close/1` is much safer.

Comment: I'm curious at where the information on the unreliability of tell and told can be found, can you kindly point me to the source?

Comment: You find an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269971/prolog-how-to-save-file-in-an-existing-file/8270091#8270091)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, why it fails :
You use fail to provoke backtracking, which can be a good technique, but not there. Because it will make your predicate false in the end, when member has ran out of solutions. Then, once loop_through_list is false, told isn't reached and the writing isn't made properly (when I test it, the file is created but nothing is written).
If you use :

```
loop_through_list([]).
loop_through_list([Head|Tail]) :-
    write(Head),
    write(' '),
    loop_through_list(Tail).
```

instead, it works.

But, even with this code working, you might want to use
open(Filename, write, Stream), write(Stream, Element) and close(Stream) instead of tell and told for the reasons explained in the link at the bottom of this answer.
For example :

```
loop_through_list(_File, []) :- !.
loop_through_list(File, [Head|Tail]) :-
    write(File, Head),
    write(File, ' '),
    loop_through_list(File, Tail).

write_list_to_file(Filename,List) :-
    open(Filename, write, File),
    loop_through_list(File, List),
    close(File).
```

or

```
loop_through_list(File, List) :-
    member(Element, List),
    write(File, Element),
    write(File, ' '),
    fail.

write_list_to_file(Filename,List) :-
    open(Filename, write, File),
    \+ loop_through_list(File, List),
    close(File).
```

using your code and joel76 trick.

See [Prolog how to save file in an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269971/prolog-how-to-save-file-in-an-existing-file)
It covers the same matter.

Comment: by the way, what is the '\+'? does it mean not (e.g. '!' in C).

Comment: @chutsu : yes, it does. In SWI-pl at least (and others may tell you about other implementations), **not/1** is deprecated and the use of **\+/1** is recommended as said in this [manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1)

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see the reason to do use this method to write a list to a file.
Programming in prolog should generally not involve loops;
besides, this is not a loop structure, it's more like a hack (or even abuse).
(and just like your case leads to unexpected bugs and problems)

Just use recursion and print the elements of the list:

```
write_list([]).
write_list([H|T]):-
    write(H),
    write('  '),
    write_list(T).
```

more elegant and could be more efficient too.

other than that, using open/4 etc (ISO IO) instead of tell/1 etc (Edinburgh IO) is generally better; check [false's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269971/prolog-how-to-save-file-in-an-existing-file)

Answer (score 2):

predicate **loop_through_list(List),** always fails, so to succed you just have to write **\+loop_through_list(List),**